# Load script tag before page load

Tags: javascript, html

I have a project and I should load JS right after open tag of `body` and before any objects load.

I use this way, but I wanna know if there is a better way possible for clean code or anything else

```
<html>
<head>
.......
</head>
<body>
  <script src="./js/checkRtl.js"></script>

  <h1>Hello World</h1>
  // OTHER COMPONENTS
</body>
</html>
```

**checkRtl.js** contains

```
const lang = localStorage.getItem('userLanguage') || "en";

if (lang !== 'en')
    document.body.classList.add("rtl");
```

here I use body tag in `checkRtl` file to check if its RTL or not, but I want just check body then load objects just to don't make the page change direction of objects after they loaded.

Comment: the way you did it, already loads the js before anything else follows in the document. If you wanted that js to be execute after the document was ready you needed to use the `defer` attribute on your script tag but you want the opposite. Anyway I'm afraid that body won't be in the dom until the whole body tag was evaluated to the end so your only chance here might be to wait for the document to be ready before evaluating that statement

Comment: JS is evaluated on load, so there's not really a way to force it to execute before any of your other elements render. You could hide everything in the body tag (with display: none, for example) and then show it after your JS runs, or alternatively, use a cookie and inject the class with PHP or whatever server language you're using. I'd recommend the latter as it will prevent the user from seeing a flicker or the page layout changing during loading.

Comment: JS is evaluated as soon as the parser finds it in the document (not on load.. that is pretty ambiguous) .. unless explicitely told differently like using the defer attribute.

Comment: Ok instead of on load how about "as soon as the JS loads"? Tomato tomahto. There could also be latency in the browser fetching the JS, so the exact moment it executes is not so cut and dry.

Comment: I think you can change classList even 5 minutes after the page loaded. There is no need to "load as soon as possible".

Comment: @DiegoDeVita Thank you so much, yeah i tried lot of ways to do same, but in al of them, at first objects load then after milliseconds change direction of the page and objects, and it doesn't satisfied me

Comment: to partially compensate that problem, you could do like @Liftoff suggested, hiding the body by default using a css rule in your page `body{visibility:hidden;}` and doing `document.querySelector('body').style.visibility= 'visible'` in your js function after it checked the language and eventually added a css class to the body.

Answer (score 0):

The way you're doing it currently just great. If I were you, I'd store it in the header to be a bit cleaner, as thats where you import things, but otherwise it's perfectly fine here.

Comment: I tried it actually but i got an error something like ```body is not defined```

Comment: Could you should the full error?